# why does my node js keeps getting stuck whenever I try and .load a mongoose js script?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

```
console.log("test")
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose
  .connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/shopDB", {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("connection open");
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    console.log("ERROR:");
    console.log(e);
  });
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    maxlength: 20,
  },
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    min: [0, "the price cant be negative, unlike the negachin >:)"],
  },
  isOnsale: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  categories: {
    type: [String],
    default: ["none"],
  },
  qty: {
    online: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    instore: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  size: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["S", "M", "L"],
  },
});

productSchema.methods.greet = function (){
  console.log("How you doin?")
}

const Product = mongoose.model("Product", productSchema);
```

everytime I am trying to use .load to run this script or one similar to it the node just endlessly prints out the first line, can anyone help? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg8cd.png)I have tried looking for a reason for a while now and I cant seem to find it

I need to able to load the script in the node terminal so I cant access what its variables inside the node terminal(an exercise for an online course I am taking)

Comment: How exactly are you loading the script?  Are you loading it with something like pm that auto-restarts if there's an error?  That seems the logical explanation for it looping.  There's apparently an error in this script and something is constantly trying to start it over and over again.

Comment: @jfriend00 no I just use the .load command while in the node terminal

Comment: What happens if you run it from the command line, not a terminal?  Do you see any type of error?

Comment: @jfriend00 if I run it in the cmd using node product.js it works fine